# Configuring RRL on a DNS server using BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, rate-limiting

I'd like to configure a DNS server to use Response Rate Limiting (RRL) to mitigate DNS DDoS attacks.
Whatever, I have to configure it top use RRL with the 'slip' parameter at 2.

I've made some search, but I haven't found anything really clear about this parameter.
The only thing I found said it represents "*how many UDP requests can be answered with a truncated response.*" and that "*setting to '2' means every other query gets a short answer*".
Source: 
https://conference.apnic.net/data/37/apricot-2014-rrl_1393309768.pdf (slide 26)

What does that mean?
If the DNS server receive 3 UDP requests, the last one will be truncated?
But for how long?

Answer (score 2):

The `slip` parameter affects how rate-limited responses are processed. Say, for example, 8 responses would be rate-limited. By the default `slip=2`, 4 of those responses (every other one) would be a truncated response and 4 would just not be sent. With `slip=0`, no responses would be sent at all. with `slip=1`, 8 truncated responses would be sent.  with `slip=4`, 2 truncated responses would be sent.

Basically, slip allows some responses to get through ("slip through") if they would otherwise be blocked by RRL.

More info from the official [BIND9.10 ARM](https://www.isc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Bv910ARM.pdf) Section 6.2.16.21 "Response Rate Limiting":

> Many attacks using DNS involve UDP requests with forged source addresses. Rate limiting prevents
>   the use of BIND 9 to flood a network with responses to requests with forged source addresses, but could
>   let a third party block responses to legitimate requests. There is a mechanism that can answer some
>   legitimate requests from a client whose address is being forged in a flood. Setting
>   slip
>   to 2 (its default)
>   causes every other UDP request to be answered with a small truncated (TC=1) response. The small size
>   and reduced frequency, and so lack of amplification, of ”slipped” responses make them unattractive
>   for reflection DoS attacks.
>   slip
>   must be between 0 and 10. A value of 0 does not ”slip”: no truncated
>   responses are sent due to rate limiting, all responses are dropped. A value of 1 causes every response
>   to slip; values between 2 and 10 cause every n’th response to slip. Some error responses including
>   REFUSED and SERVFAIL cannot be replaced with truncated responses and are instead leaked at the
>   slip
>   rate.